# Regular Expression does not accept correct inputs

Tags: java, regex, error-handling, expression, user-input

I am developing a Java method, which checks, if the user input is valid. For that I wrote four regular expressions to check that. The first three work fine. The last one, the "most complex" regular expression, does not accept values, which should be accepted.

I want to make sure, that the user entered one of three different input settings.

- One to six "L" followed by a number from 1-16
- One to six "R" followed by a number from 1-16
- One B followed by a number from 1-16

My problem is to define, that only numbers from 1-16 will be accepted. My regular expression is accepting 1-9, but not any number above 9.

Let's take the "B"-case for example, than this is my regular expression:

```
 String regexB = "B[([1-9]{1})((1[0-6]){1})]";
```

What I tried to do with my expression:
One "B", followed by one single number from 1-9 OR by a "1" and a second single number from 0-6.

I know, that this is possibly not a hard question, but maybe one of you guys is able to save me from losing some time by trying to solve this.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String regexB = "B([1][0-6]|[1-9])";
```

- B
- a digit 1 and 0-6 **OR**
- a digit between 1 and 9

Comment: Nice, this works fine! I didn't know, that a "|" operator can be used, since it was not mentioned in the documentation/tutorial I went through (from oracle).

Comment: @KJaeg [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) explains regexes pretty well.

Comment: @sp00m thanks. I have some knowledge about regular expressions. But since I did not use for some years, I just forgot about the syntax and the operators. So I walked through an Oracle tutorial, which was really basic. Since your link provides a lot of more detailled information, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think your regexp is invalid. 
Try the following (for B example)

```
B((1{1}[0-6]{1})|([1-9]{1}))
```

Comment: Yep, @griFlo is right. The most important use of my regular expression is to catch any number below 1 and above 16.

Comment: I edited the regexp, It might be fine now. Sorry for wrong suggestion before :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String regexB = "B([1-9]|([1][0-6]))";
```

edit: oh ... the answer is already there ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tool that will help you: http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range.

In your case: `[1-9]|1[0-6]`

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about utilitymill, will keep that in mind!